# Error in the notes about even/odd function?

Tags: solution-verification, even-and-odd-functions

Exercise:

> Be $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ two functions. $f$ is odd, and $g$ is even.
> Prove that $f(g(x))$ is odd, and $g(f(x))$ is even.

I personally think there is a mistake since both the compositions should be even. Indeed through $x \to -x$:

$$f(g(x)) \to f(g(-x)) = f(g(x))$$

$$g(f(x)) \to g(f(-x)) = g(-f(x)) = g(f(x))$$

Am I right or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You are right.  In fact, if $g$ is even, then $f \circ g$ is even for any (not necessarily odd) function $f$.

Comment: Thank you! I should trust myself more :D But thank you for the time taken to check :)